# Weird blobs all over shell

Tags: abs

I've been trying to print parts for Voron 2.4 but I'm having issues getting proper surface on walls. I'm printing with ABS. I couldn't find same problem all over the net looking at the images. Bed adhesion is quite good and printing temp is 240 °C and bed temp is around 100 °C.
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: I've seen this on ABS that has been sitting around absorbing moisture. Do you see or hear moisture cooking out as you print?

Comment: That block desperately needs a sock. :-)